# Raise exception only at the end of for loop in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, printing

I have a code like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".names.pages")

for element in elements in range(len(elements)):
    elements[element].click()
    id_page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".id.page")
    try:
        name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name")
        if name == "John":
            print("ID: " + id_page + " - " + name + " is correct name")
        else:
            print("ID: " + id_page + " - " + name + "is wrong name")
    except:
        print("Can't find the person")
        continue
```

The output is something like this but much longer list:

```
ID: 5487 - John is correct name
ID: 3553 - John is correct name
ID: 7679 - John is correct name
ID: 7677 - Sara is wrong name
ID: 3456 - John is correct name
ID: 7990 - Michael is wrong name
ID: 5654 - John is correct name
ID: 1111 - Craig is wrong name
ID: 3456 - David is wrong name
ID: 9876 - John is correct name
```

Is it possible after the loop finishes to check if there are any people with wrong names in the output list and to raise exception and print only the IDs and/or names which are wrong. If all names are correct or can't find any person to finish and print successful message for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of "wrong names" in its own list, then check for this list to contain something at the end. Pseudo code:

```
errors = []

for element in ...:
    if name_is_wrong:
        errors.append(id_page)

if errors:
    raise YourException("Wrong ids: %s" % ", ".join(errors))
else:
    print("Success")
```